# GetMapping, produces and HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException

Tags: spring-boot, versioning, get-mapping

I am trying to add versioning of my rest endpoints.  I was following the tutorial found at https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-versioning-for-rest-services.  I am using spring-boot-starter-parent 2.6.2.  I created 2 endpoints:

```
@GetMapping(value="/student/produces", produces="application/vnd.app-v1+json")
public StudentV1 producesV1() {
  return new StudentV1("AA");
}

@GetMapping(value="/student/produces", produces="application/vnd.app-v2+json")
public StudentV2 producesV2() {
  return new StudentV1(new Name("BB"));
}
```

Whenever I try to hit the endpoints (either via swagger/OAS3 or curl) I get an HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation.  None of my google-fu has helped.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. In our WebMvcConfigurer.configureContentNegotiation we had set contentNegotiationConfigurer.ignoreAcceptHeader to true.  Changed it to false and all is good.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).